# Using Boolean Module as filter in Views

Tags: 7, views

We are trying to use Boolean module inside Drupal 7 to define a boolean field for a custom content type , `news` .

the module seems to be enabled without any visible issues . the issue comes when we wish to use that boolean field's data for Filtering in a view.

e.g The boolean field is called `editor-choice` , in the View we wish to get all `news` content type that is published and has Editor's choice value to true.  please see below screenshots of the three steps being performed.

[image: choosing the field to use for filter]

[image: choosing what value to use for Filter]

[image: error message]

kindly assist what can be the possible issue, or if possible, suggest some other plugin that may be used foe this purpose.

Comment: Boolean field is already available in Drupal7. May I ask why you need to use boolean module to achieve that?

Comment: could not find a boolean field by default :) . can you guide by which name it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Drupal latest version, boolean field is available by default in core.

Goto your content type => Manage field => Add new field => Select field type

[image]

In the manage field configuration, give 'on' value and 'off' value. Here I have given, Yes and No.

[image]

In the views filter, select the option you wish to filter. Thats it.

[image]

Comment: ok. thank you got it :) . can you also guide in more small thing about Views.. it seems that it is repeating the contents. e.g. currently only one node value was set to true but it is repeating 2-3 times.

Comment: updated the answer. pls check